# Cannot connect to Xen domU via VNC if X isn't installed on domU

Tags: xen, vnc

I'm trying to build a Xen domU that can be connected through the Xen's VNC server. Below is the template (actually it's generated by OpenNebula):

```
name = 'one-153'
#O CPU_CREDITS = 256
memory  = '128'
bootloader = "/usr/bin/pygrub"
disk = ['tap:aio:/home/oneadmin/cloud/one/var/153/images/disk.0,xvda,w',]
vif = ['mac=02:00:c0:a8:00:03,bridge=virbr0',]
vfb = ['type=vnc,vnclisten=slave1,vncdisplay=1,vncpasswd=v98KXdFN']
```

The problem is that I can't connect to the domU if it doesn't have X. In this case all I got is a blank screen. Besides, if the domU has X, the screen is still blank until the login prompt appears, while it should be like [this](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Image:Xen_vnc_no_desktop.jpg).

Some information that may be useful:

- The domU and the dom0 both run CentOS 5.5.
- If the domU has X, it can be connected even when both X and the domU's VNC server isn't running.
- The VNC client is RealVNC.

Comment: Quite odd ... Lets say that your Dom0 is 1.1.1.1 and your guest is 1.1.1.2 ... You are trying to connect to 1.1.1.1:1, right ? Try removing vnclisten=slave1.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. By the way slave1 is dom0

Comment: On Dom0, what is the output of 'netstat -tnl | grep :59' ? This should at least return a line telling that vnc server is listening on port 5901.

Comment: The output is `tcp 0 0 192.168.44.130:5901 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`.

Comment: update you question with the output of "iptables -L -n"

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: No, I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: If I should guess it is not related to X but to the video mode used on the virtual framebuffer

Answer (score -1):

So VNC needs an X-server. When I look at the services started by vnc (xinetd on CentOS 5) there is alway X involved.

Comment: VNC needs something to provide session content. X is the most common or most familiar. QEMU can be set to support VNC to its console and thus you'd have VNC to something that isn't actually X, and doesn't even need X in it. In theory you can make a VNC server serve any kind of content you can program.