# Connecting to xen domU console using vnc

Tags: xen, vnc, console

To follow this question :

[Cannot connect to Xen domU via VNC if X isn't installed on domU](https://serverfault.com/questions/199670/cannot-connect-to-xen-domu-via-vnc-if-x-isnt-installed-on-domu)

I'm able to connect using VNC but only see the login screen, not the whole boot process log (and pygrub menu) which I want to see.

on DomU, menu.lst :

```
kernel          /boot/[...] console=hvc0 xencons=tty0
```

domU's configuration file :

```
vfb = [ 'vnc=1' ]
```

in domu's /etc/init/hvc0.conf

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 hvc0
```

also created /etc/init/tty0.conf (just in case)

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty0
```

"dmesg | grep console" on domU gives :

```
[    0.000000] Command line: root=/dev/xvda2 ro console=hvc0 xencons=tty0 root=/dev/sda2 ro 
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/xvda2 ro console=hvc0 xencons=tty0 root=/dev/sda2 ro 
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] console [hvc0] enabled
[    0.129419] XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/console/0
```

I can't figure out why, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Don`t use console and xencons as kernel-options and you should see everything in vnc.

I had the opposite problem: With vnc enabled I did not see the boot-process on the console - only in vnc. Solution was: disable vnc, put xencons=tty - so I guess you are redirecting the output to the text-console.